# Get specific key values in a list of maps with Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Being new to Elixir I'm having some problems understanding pattern matching.

If I have an Elixir data structure like this:

```
list_with_maps = [%{"id" => 1, "name" => "a"}, %{"id" => 2, "name" => "b"}]
```

What would be the best way to get values of all id fields from it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can map over the list and return the id using [Enum.map/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#map/2)

```
Enum.map(list_with_maps, fn (x) -> x["id"] end)
[1, 2]
```

You can write the same function using the [capture](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1) operator:

```
Enum.map(list_with_maps, & &1["id"])
```

I prefer writing `& &1["id"]` as `&(&1["id"])` but the parentheses are optional.

Answer (score 10):

A more generic (and simpler) way of getting a subset of the keys of a `Map` is to use `Map.take/2`, which you can use like this:

```
map = %{"id" => 1, "name" => "a"}
Map.take(map, ["id"])
> %{"id" => 1}
```

As you can see, it takes an array of keys and returns a new map with only the keys you want.

Now, applying this to a list is as simple as using a map, and then using the `Map.take/2` in mapper function. As has been pointed out, you can do this using either a lambda:

```
Enum.map(list_with_maps, fn (map) -> Map.take(map, ["id"]) end)
```

Or you can use a capture:

```
Enum.map(list_with_maps, &(Map.take(&1, ["id"])))
```

This will create more intermediate maps, but for most situations that won't be a problem, as Elixir is pretty smart about memory re-usage and won't actually create these objects a lot of the times, unles

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness for the answers for this question you could also do something like this:

```
defmodule Test do
  def get_all_ids([head | tail ]) do
    IO.puts head["id"]
    get_all_ids(tail)
  end

  def get_all_ids([]) do
    IO.puts "end"
  end
end
```

Which would be used like so:

```
iex(7)> Test.get_all_ids(list_with_maps)
1
2
end
:ok
```

Although I think @Gazler's answer is the better answer in this case.

Oh and since you specifically mentioned pattern matching, this would also work:

```
defmodule Test do
  def get_all_ids([%{"id" => id} = m  | tail ]) do
    IO.puts id
    get_all_ids(tail)
  end

  def get_all_ids([]) do
    IO.puts "end"
  end
end
```

The call would be exactly the same; the difference in the second approach is that it's using a pattern match to parse the map in the argument list.

You might also change the argument list in this line: `def get_all_ids([%{"id" => id} = m  | tail ]) do` to this: `def get_all_ids([%{"id" => id} = _m  | tail ]) do` just to avoid the warning about `m` being unused.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the name value from the list of maps

```
names = for %{name: n, id: _} <- list_with_maps, do: n
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `get_in` function and leveraging the `Access` module. The Access module lets you build expressive ways of dealing with nested data structures.

To get a list of values at `"id"` you could run:

```
get_in(list_with_maps, [Access.all, "id"])
```

Passing `Access.all` as the first element in the list, followed by `"id"` tells `get_in` to return all `list_with_maps`'s `"id"` value.

It may seem like overkill for this example, but if your structure looked like:

```
list_with_maps = [%{"id" => 1, "identities" => [%{"name" => "a"}, %{"name" => "Secret A"}]}, %{"id" => 2, "identities" => [%{"name" => "b"},%{"name" => "Secret B"}]}]
```

We could get all of the names with:

```
get_in(list_with_maps, [Access.all, "identities", Access.all, "name"])
# [["a", "Secret A"], ["b", "Secret B"]]
```